# How to use Rest API and PHP

Tags: php, api

Very beginner question but simply do not know where to begin. I am trying to obtain a response with this API using PHP but cannot get anything to work.

I know the problem has something to do with HTTP Components but I'm a total beginner and very stuck.

Any help would be great or perhaps if there's another (cleaner and easier) way to do this would be great as well.

I am trying to get the response in json format

```html
<?php
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new Http_Request2('https://services.last10k.com/v1/company/{ticker}/ratios');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '{subscription key}',
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}

?>
```